# Git commit to multiple branches, how do I find which branches the commit went to?

Tags: git

If you commit a file(s) to multiple branches, how can you look up which branches that commit is a part of?

Comment: What do you mean by "Commit to multiple branches"?

Answer (score 2):

The answer *might* be `git branch --contains`, but the question is not well formed.

In Git, a commit is a complete snapshot of every file.  More precisely, each commit identifies what Git calls a *tree* object, and the tree itself lists file names, their modes (100644 or 100755), and what Git calls a *blob* hash ID—the "true name" of the file stored in Git's internal database, by which Git can extract the file's data.  (Each tree can also list sub-trees, which then list more file names and so on.)

A commit also has a hash ID.  This hash ID is unique: it identifies that one particular commit.  But `2512f15446149235156528dafbe75930c712b29e` is not exactly useful to *humans*; we like nice names like `v2.16.0`.  So Git allows us to use branch and/or tag names to identify one specific commit.

Every commit can also list additional commit hash IDs, and most list exactly one such hash ID.  These are the commit's *parent* commits.  When the commit we call `v2.16.0` has exactly one parent (`e0d575025a80c83c3eaec82a217714610f0ab115`, in fact), it means that commit `2512f15...` comes after `e0d57502...` in history—or in Git's terms, history *is* that `2512f15...` is immediately preceded by `e0d57502...`.  If we start at the later commit, we can move back in time to look at the earlier one.  If we compare the two saved *snapshots*, we'll see what *changed* in that time period:

```
$ git show 2512f15446149235156528dafbe75930c712b29e
commit 2512f15446149235156528dafbe75930c712b29e (tag: v2.16.0)
Author: Junio C Hamano ... [snippage]
diff --git a/GIT-VERSION-GEN b/GIT-VERSION-GEN
index 258aff35c..e4c858d35 100755
--- a/GIT-VERSION-GEN
+++ b/GIT-VERSION-GEN
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 #!/bin/sh

 GVF=GIT-VERSION-FILE
-DEF_VER=v2.16.0-rc2
+DEF_VER=v2.16.0

 LF='
 '
```

Meanwhile, a branch name like `master` simply identifies *one specific commit*:

```
$ git rev-parse master
5be1f00a9a701532232f57958efab4be8c959a29
```

If we start at this commit and work backwards through time, following each commit to its parent commit(s), perhaps we will reach commit `2512f15446149235156528dafbe75930c712b29e`:

```
$ git branch --contains 2512f15446149235156528dafbe75930c712b29e
* master
```

and yes, in fact, `master` (commit `5be1f00...`) *does* eventually reach back to `2512f15...`.

So, one possible answer to your question is to use `git branch --contains`: give it a commit hash ID, and it will tell you *every* branch name that, if Git starts from the commit to which that branch name points and works backwards, eventually leads to that particular commit.

But there's a problem: you phrased this as:

> If you commit a file(s) to multiple branches ...

and when you run `git commit`, what Git does is to create a *new* commit.  The new-commit-creation process makes a *new* commit, which clearly does not—at least not yet—exist on *any* branch:

```
$ git write-tree
8ccb7d4fa49449a843b00aca64baf99feb10e2ab
```

This is a new tree made from the index: it's the snapshot for the new commit.

```
$ git commit-tree -p HEAD -m message 8ccb7d4fa49449a843b00aca64baf99feb10e2ab
aa123a5b9d43186143b6e43cfeca434a67bab9f3
$ git cat-file -p aa123a5b9d43186143b6e43cfeca434a67bab9f3 | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 8ccb7d4fa49449a843b00aca64baf99feb10e2ab
parent 5be1f00a9a701532232f57958efab4be8c959a29
author Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1518104686 -0800
committer Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1518104686 -0800

message
$ git branch --contains aa123a5b9d43186143b6e43cfeca434a67bab9f3
$
```

So *no* branch contains this new commit, yet.  But when we use the normal way to make commits (rather than `git write-tree` and `git commit-tree`), the *last* step is that `git commit` itself *changes* the current branch—in my case, `master`—so that the current branch name points to the new commit just made.

This means that if I were to run:

```
$ git add somefile
$ git commit
```

I'd get a *new* commit that has, as its snapshot, everything in the index right now plus the added file `somefile`.  Git would make my `master` branch point to this one new commit I just added.  Since the commit is *new*, no *other* branch could possibly lead back to this new commit.  Hence *only one branch* can contain it, that being the branch I'm on right now.

Hence:

> how can you look up which branches that commit is a part of?

If you've only just now made the commit, that one single commit is only on *one* branch: it's on the branch you are on right now.  And this conflicts with the conditional part of the question:

> If you commit a file(s) to multiple branches ...

The (single) commit *C* is only "on" the one branch you were on when you made it.  You didn't really commit the file *to* a branch, you committed the file *to* a commit (well, that's kind of vacuous, but true enough) and then added the *commit* to the branch.

Later, you might have moved other branch names—perhaps via `git merge` or `git reset` commands—and/or created additional new branch names that either *point to* commit *C*, or have commit *C* in their history (as formed by following their actual head commit parent hash IDs).  It's at that time that you can find multiple branch names that contain commit *C*.

Or, you could be asking an entirely different question, such as: "If I have some number of commits that have, in their stored trees, a file whose path is *P*, and I have other commits where there is *no* file with path *P*, how can I find *all* the commits reachable from *all* current branch heads in which the stored commit has a file whose path is *P?*"  In this case the answer is *not* `git branch --contains`, but that's not the question I have answered.